# Force SublimeREPL to use specific version of Ruby

Tags: sublime-text-2, ruby, sublime-text-3, version

I installed [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/) for use with Ruby. It attempts to run code on Ruby 1.8.7 and I would like it to run on 1.9.3, and later on other versions of Ruby. I'm not sure where it's inheriting the environment from. Currently my PATH is:

```
/home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin
/home/user/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin
/home/user/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global/bin
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/home/user/bin
/home/user/bin
/home/user/.rvm/bin
```

(formatted for readability)
I added the following to the settings page for SublimeREPL:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "/home/user/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby:{PATH}"}
}
```

(as well as trying the reverse, "{PATH}:/home...").
Attempting to run the repl results in an error:

```
/home/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:296 ... (unimportant error)
```

Clearly it's not using ruby 1.9.3. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your `PATH` should only contain directories, not specific files, so the `"default_extend_env"` value should be `/home/user/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin`. However, there is a way to create a menu option to run PRY with the `ruby` binary in that directory. Open your `Packages/User` directory by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**, then entering the `User` directory. Once there, create the following directory structure: `SublimeREPL/config/Ruby`. Next, in Sublime, create a new JSON file with the following contents:

```json
[
  {
    "id":"tools",
    "children":[
      {
        "caption":"SublimeREPL",
        "mnemonic":"r",
        "id":"SublimeREPL",
        "children":[
          {
            "caption":"Ruby 1.9.3",
            "children":[
              {
                "command":"repl_open",
                "caption":"Ruby",
                "id":"repl_ruby",
                "mnemonic":"r",
                "args":{
                  "type":"subprocess",
                  "external_id":"ruby",
                  "encoding":"utf8",
                  "cmd":{
                    "linux":[
                      "/home/user/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby",
                      "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/pry_repl.rb",
                      "$editor"
                    ]
                  },
                  "soft_quit":"\nexit\n",
                  "cwd":"$file_path",
                  "cmd_postfix":"\n",
                  "autocomplete_server": true,
                  "syntax":"Packages/Ruby/Ruby.tmLanguage"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and save it as `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/Main.sublime-menu`. Now, if you go to **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Ruby`** there should be a `Ruby 1.9.3` menu option you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me. Now, though, it can't find pry even though it's installed for 1.9.3. Looks like a problem with `gem env`, it says my ruby exec is 1.9.3 but the executable dir, installation dir and most importantly gem paths are all 1.8.7

Comment: @DevonParsons try adding all your Ruby 1.9.3 paths from your `PATH` variable to the `"default_extend_env"` variable. If you're interested, take a look at `Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/pry_repl.rb` to see what's required.